# Regarding the implementation of Power.asm

Tags: assembly, nand2tetris

> An Assembly code that does Power:
> • Implement an Assembly program to calculate the exponential power of a
> given number n, P(n,e).
> o For Example. If n = 2 and e = 5 than P(n,e) would be = 2*2*2*2*2 = 32.
> • The user should enter the value of the number n into R0. i.e. RAM[0] and e into R1
> i.e. RAM[1].
> • The result P(n,e) should be saved in RAM[2].
> • SPECIAL CASE: In 
>
> If e is ZERO, your Program should store 1 in RAM[0]
> and ends the program.

Been doing some studies on asm. For this particular question on power.asm, a sample answer was given as shown below, although I don't quite understand, like why is there an @2 before M=0 & @1 after it? Is anyone able to help to explain this code on **power.asm** to me? Thank you.

```
    @2
    M=0  
    @1
    D=M 
    @EXIT
    D;JEQ
    @POWER
    D;JGT

(EXIT) 
    @1
    D=A
    @2  
    M=D  
    @0
    M=D  
    @END  
    0;JMP
    
(POWER)
    @0
    D=M
    @2  
    M=D  // set up first iteration, power of 1
    @END  // if the first iteration is 1, no need to add anymore, since multiples of 1 is 1
    D-1;JEQ
    
    

(LOOP)
    @0
    D=M  
    @3
    M=D-1 
    
    @2
    D=M 
    @4
    M=D  
    
    @1
    M=M-1   
    D=M
    @MULT 
    D;JLT
    @END  
    D;JEQ

(MULT)
    @4
    D=M 
    @2
    M=D+M    
    
    @3
    M=M-1 
    D=M
    @MULT           
    D;JGT
    @LOOP  
    D;JEQ
    
    
(END)
    0;JMP
```

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to review Chapter 5 of the Nand2Tetris course, in particular the operation of A instructions.

In short:

- @ loads  into the A (Address) register
- M represents the value at ram location A
- D is the data register

So:

- @2 loads 2 into the A register
- M=0 stores 0 into RAM[2]
- @1 loads 1 into the A register
- D=M loads RAM[1] into the D register

And so on.